# Configure fluent assertions precision for comparing decimal

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am writing unit test using fluent-assertions and sqlite which stores badly decimal type.

I would like **ALL** my decimal comparison to ignore the floating part.

Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

FluentAssertions allows for approximation assertions for decimal / floating point numeric values.

> The following method is specifically designed for floating point or
>   decimal variables.
>
> ```
> float value = 3.1415927F;
> value.Should().BeApproximately(3.14F, 0.01F);
> ```
>
> This will verify that the value of the float is between `3.139` and
>   `3.141`.

### Reference [FluentAssertions Documentation: Numeric types and everything else that implements `IComparable<T>`](https://fluentassertions.com/numerictypes/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want that *ALL* my assertions on decimal types uses this precision settings. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

As Nkosi pointed out we can use `BeApproximately`. Combine with `Using` and `WhenTypeIs` to apply it to all decimals within an object graph:

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Value1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Value2 { get; set; }
}

var fooActual = new Foo { Value1 = 1.001M, Value2 = 2.002M };
var fooExpected = new Foo { Value1 = 1.003M, Value2 = 2.005M };

fooActual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(
    fooExpected,
    options => options
        .Using<decimal>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(ctx.Expectation, 0.01M))
        .WhenTypeIs<decimal>()
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me because I can use BeEquivalentTo() on objects or lists where there can be many different value types.