# Newtonsoft.Json - Numbers in Json file get incorrectly identified as being int when they're floats during serialisation

Tags: json, json.net, .net-4.8

On a project, running on .NET 4.8 I'm executing a call to a web service, this call then returns a JSON, which needs to be processed.

I created the C# classes (long live [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/)) and decided to write a unit test to validate classes. In other words, to check if the generated classes are a good fit for the data being offered.

I did a bit of research on the subject and found a couple of usable references:

- https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20220520-ComparingJsonStringsInUnitTests.html
- [How to compare two Json objects using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645603/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-using-c-sharp)

As more or less demonstrated in my examples, I'm loading the JSON from a file, parsing it into objects as I do in the actual code, and then check whether or not what's in the objects corresponds with the JSON file.

Serialization and deserialization aren't creating issues, the verification however...

The JSON response provided by the web service is rather lengthy, a complex nested structure. Certain of the items can even be found several times in the same response, alone or as part of a different sub-structure.

Of course, in C# this means reusing the same class, but... in certain cases, one instance of data  the numbers are displayed in decimal format, in others as plain integers.

```
   {
       "result": [
           {
                "In": {
                    "consumer": {
                       "tax": 65.00
                    }
                },
                "Out": {
                    "consumer": {
                       "tax": 65
                    },
                }
           }
       ]
   }
```

This is a very simplified JSON of course.

As a result, when I run my unit test, it fails. It gets a float where it expects an int or one time an int is expected, and other times a float:

[image: Results]

I attempted to solve this by creating multiple versions of the impacted classes, but... sometimes modifying the type to what the unit test expects breaks the conversion itself.
T
The unit test looks like his:

```
[TestClass]
public class CheckSerializationOfRequestAndResponseJsons : TestsBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ResponseJsons_ShouldBeEqualAsExpected()
    {
        var expectedJson = LoadJson("SomeJson.json");

        //  Generate a base object model using a generalized structure
        var expected = JToken.Parse(expectedJson);

        //  Generating an object model using the defined classes
        var actualModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonContainer>(expectedJson);

        //  Converting the new object back into json
        var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actualModel);

        //  Generating a new object using a generalized structure
        var actual = JToken.Parse(actualJson);

        //  Comparing the 2
        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

My Dto's look like this:

```
   /// <summary>Tax</summary>
   public class Tax
   {
       /// <summary>Tax - total charge</summary>
       [JsonProperty("tax", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
       public double? Tax;
   }
```

I'm not going to include the entire code, since that's a bit outside of the scope of my question.

The approach used is based on **FluentAssertions**

```
using FluentAssertions.Json;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

I found another issue... Capitalization!

I prefer to follow stand naming conventions, but this also see
My question is... what can I do?

- Is there a way for me to force a certain field to be imported as a float?
- Or is my approach for the unit test the problem?

Comment: the issue is : when you parsing original json - it loads tax as "tax": 65 - integer, when you convert to class and back - it treats as decimal

Comment: you can play with accretion to adjust https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384306/configure-fluent-assertions-precision-for-comparing-decimal but you comparing apples and oranges, since you converting to class and back - it changes json and original have int value. it will work if you will not have integers like 65 and replace with 65.0

Comment: The problem is the original output doesn't contain uniform number formatting. So it doesn't matter what I do I think. :-( I'll keep on running into the same issue... depending on what the 1st number is hat is encountered FluentAssertions will be expecting an int or  a float, and since it's a combination of both factors..

Comment: Basically, I need to change the approach of my unit test I think.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you would like is to treat 65.00 (float) equals to 65 (int) in json ?
If that is case, can you try this Xunit json assertion [package](https://github.com/lateapexearlyspeed/Lateapexearlyspeed.JsonSchema) which considered this situation because this (int/float) case is defined in "Json Schema spec" and this library implemented it.

For your example, this assertion will pass:

```cs
string actualJson = """
{
    "consumer": {
        "tax": 65.00
    }
}
""";

string expectedJson = """
{
    "consumer": {
        "tax": 65
    }
}
""";

JsonAssertion.Equivalent(expectedJson, actualJson);
```

(I am author of that library)

Comment: It's close to the issue @ hand. 

The response I have to parse consists of a compilation of the outcome of x other calls, and... to be fun... each of the calls has its own format. They then build a new output Json from these results. But... and here is the issue... in certain fiels you get a combination of ints and floats. In my current evaluation that situation fails, I need it not to fail.

Comment: So I actually need to have everything parsed as a float in certain situations.

Comment: @Fysicus ok, just remind library mentioned above should already consider this kind of numeric type compatibility, you should not need to convert by yourself by using that :)